# What does 'build with master branch of ...' mean?

Tags: compiling, github

I'm trying to install ios-webkit-debug-proxy. and while running 'make' I get following error.

```
webinspector.c: In function 'idevice_connection_get_fd_wrapper':
webinspector.c:50:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'idevice_connection_get_fd' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   idevice_error_t err = idevice_connection_get_fd(connection, &fd);
```

I find sort of an advice on the github page of this probject

> error during compilation
>
> ```
> implicit declaration of function 'idevice_connection_get_fd' is invalid in C99
> idevice_error_t err = idevice_connection_get_fd(connection, &fd);
> ```
>
> Build with master branch of libimobildevice or if you're using homebrew >brew uninstall libimobiledevice && brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice

as I'm trying to install this on linux (ubuntu), I don't have homebrew.

What do they mean with 'Build with master branch of libimobildevice'?

Comment: If you can provide a link I may be better able to ascertain the meaning, but from the information you've provided it sounds like they are abusing the term "master" and should simply be saying "Build using the 'libimobildevice' branch."

Comment: https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy

It's in the troubleshouting section of the readme

Answer (score 1):

The default branch of a development tree in git is called `master`, and usually this branch is used as the main branch.

clone it using git and `cd` into the directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.git
cd libimobiledevice
```

Normally the master branch will be checked out by default, check it with:

```
git status -b
```

Or checkout the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
```

To compile run:

```
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```